# Why is my custom spinner disabled/unresponsive?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I've created a custom spinner, because again and again, I found that I wanted to make sure that the `onItemSelectedListener` wasn't triggered when I set my Spinner's initial selection or set a new custom adapter. I only want it triggered when a user actually selects an item.

But for some reason (I'm at a complete loss as to why), my custom spinner doesn't respond to touch events. It's as if it's disabled, even though I've debugged and seen that it's perfectly enabled. But for some reason, my little spinner won't open. Can anyone help me understand why?

Here's the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <my.app.custom.view.MySpinner
        android:id="@+id/dog_or_cat_toggle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:entries="@array/dog_or_cat"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@drawable/top_to_bottom_gray_gradient"/>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

And my Custom Spinner:

```
/* A Spinner dispatches an onItemSelected event when the View is initialized, before the user ever makes a selection.
 * This class allows listeners for just the initial selection, just user selections, or both. */
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {
    private boolean initialized = false;
    private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectionInitializedListener;
    private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedByUserListener;
    private OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener;

    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.initializeMySpinner();
    }

    public void setOnItemSelectionInitializedListener(OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectionInitializedListener) {
        this.onItemSelectionInitializedListener = onItemSelectionInitializedListener;
    }

    public void setOnItemSelectedByUserListener(OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedByUserListener) {
        this.onItemSelectedByUserListener = onItemSelectedByUserListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener) {
        this.onItemSelectedListener = onItemSelectedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        this.initialized = false;
        super.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initializeMySpinner() {
        super.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(!initialized) {
                    if(onItemSelectionInitializedListener != null) onItemSelectionInitializedListener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
                    if(onItemSelectedListener != null) onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
                    initialized = true;
                } else {
                    if(onItemSelectedListener != null) onItemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
                    if(onItemSelectedByUserListener != null) onItemSelectedByUserListener.onItemSelected(parent, view, position, id);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                if(!initialized) {
                    if(onItemSelectionInitializedListener != null) onItemSelectionInitializedListener.onNothingSelected(parent);
                    if(onItemSelectedListener != null) onItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(parent);
                    initialized = true;
                } else {
                    if(onItemSelectedListener != null) onItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(parent);
                    if(onItemSelectedByUserListener != null) onItemSelectedByUserListener.onNothingSelected(parent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://pastebin.com/raw/mXAq3n4g

Comment: you dont need to any custom `Spinner` class: see the code above, but if you really want it then replace `this(context, attrs, 0);` with `this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.spinnerStyle);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call one constructor from another. Instead, call super() constructor from each one.

I have faced the same issue some time back and this trick worked, but I'm not sure about the reason.

Comment: I love you Bob. That fixed it.

Comment: if you dont know why this happens then replace `this(context, attrs, 0);` with `this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.spinnerStyle);`